# PHP - PDO - Try Catch

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

Quiero entender por qué ocurre lo siguiente:

Tengo en un archivo PHP (index.php) la instanciación de una clase y el uso del método **`register()`**. El tema es que el `try catch` no me toma las excepciones y a pesar de que el registro no se realiza en la base de datos si me incrementa el auto-incremental del id. No importa si escribo mal la query, o si intento insertar registros con campos repetidos en un campo de tipo `UNIQUE`. A continuación las evidencias. Basicamente quiero entender por que no se ejecuta el catch y todo el try se ejecuta a pesar de que hay errores con la Query, no importa si uso Throwable, Exception o PDOException.

Código index.php:

```html
<?php

require 'src/Classes/Account.php';


$reg = new Account();
$reg->register('Alfredossss', 'Serranosss', 'Prueba2sss');
echo "Registro Satisfactorio";
```

Dicha instanciacion proviene de la clase Account

Código Account.php:

```html
<?php


require_once 'database/Conexion.php';

class Account
{
    public function register($username, $password, $email)
    {   
        
        $pdo = Conexion::openConnection();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO account (username, password, email, created_on) VALUES (?,?,?,now())";    
        
        try {
            $pdo->beginTransaction();
                $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute([$username, $password, $email]);
            $pdo->commit();
            Conexion::closeConnection();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            echo "Mensaje de Error: " . $th->getMessage();
        }
                               
    }
}
```

Que a su vez se conecta con el archivo database/Conexion.php de la clase Conexion

Código Conexion.php:

```html
class Conexion
{
    public static $db;
    private static $user = '*****';
    private static $password = '****';


    public static function openConnection()
    {
        return self::$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax', self::$user, self::$password);

    }
    public static function closeConnection()
    {
        self::$db = null;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código SQL:

```html
CREATE TABLE account(
 user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 last_login TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Has probado a poner $pdo->rollback() en el catch? No estás cerrando las consultas malas y puede (no estoy seguro) afectar en el id

Comment: Si, tengo un método para ello, lo puedes ver en el archivo Conexion.php pero no lo estaba invocando, ya lo corregí gracias, sin embargo cerrar la conexión no evita que se siga auto-incrementando el id a pesar de un error en la query. A no ser que esté cerrando mal la conexión. `$pdo->commit();
            Conexion::closeConnection();`

Comment: La conexión la cierras después del catch?

Comment: La cierro despues del $pdo->commit(); Voy a editar la publicación para que se aprecie mejor.

Comment: Porque no pruebas \Exception $e en lugar de Throwable y nos cuentas que tal fue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que descubrí por que no te salta el catch, añade a tu conexión los atributos PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE: y PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION para reporte de errores:

```
self::$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax', self::$user, self::$password);
self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return self::$db;
```

Déjalo de esta manera, te saltará cualquier error que tengas en la consulta.

En la función, prueba esta manera como dice el compañero:

```
$pdo = Conexion::openConnection();
$pdo->beginTransaction();

try {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO account (username, password, email, created_on) VALUES (?,?,?,now())";

    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$username, $password, $email]);
    $pdo->commit();

} catch (\Throwable $th) {

    $pdo->rollBack() ;
    echo "Mensaje de Error: " . $th->getMessage();
}
Conexion::closeConnection();
```

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudó a mostrar las excepciones, pero por alguna extraña razón que desconozco me sigue autoincrementando el ID cuando no realiza ningun registro por un error, conoces una forma de evitar que los errores no incrementen el id?

Comment: Creo te falta un rollback dentro del bloque catch

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz Es el comportamiento esperado de los autoincrement, no se podrá revertir esto, su pregunta no se basa en esa opción si no escribiría la respuesta. Puede  leer la [referecia , (Modifying AUTO_INCREMENT)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) No tendría por qué preocuparse por ese id caso contrario tendrá que trabajarlo de otra forma.

Comment: la apertura de conexion deberia estar antes del try, y el cierre despues el catch. sino, en tu ejemplo puede quedar la conexion abierta. añadiria tambien el beginTransaction antes del try. Dentro del try al final haces commit, y en el catch haces rollback. Sino, otra opcion es en el finally cerrar la conexion.

Comment: Gracias por enseñarme la manera correcta.

Comment: Ciertamente  el autoincrement esta establecido para autoincrementarse de realizarse un INSERT o no (Motivado a una excepción), pensaba que solo se autoincrementaba si y solo sí se realizaba el INSERT. Para ello voy a aplicar validaciones en el código para así evitar que llegue a la ejecución del método register con errores. Sin embargo no es necesario agregar la variable $sql dentro del Try Catch, y me interesa abrir la conexión solo si se va a ejecutar el insert, por eso abro la conexión dentro del try catch, por lo que esa pieza del código la dejaré igual. Muchas gracias por las respuestas.